# MemoryCache expiration value .NET

Tags: c#, .net, caching, model-view-controller, memorycache

I'm trying to cache some values and my goal is to keep them until they get overwritten. So basically they should never expire.

```
var memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;

if (!memoryCache.Contains("data"))
{
    var timer = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1);
    var data = jsonContent;

    memoryCache.Add("data", data, timer);
}
```

How can I work around the expiration parameter? I've read something about the `CacheItemPolicy` but I didn't understand it.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation it seems that you can set the`SlidingExpiration` property on the `CacheItemPolicy` object to `NoSlidingExpiration` which seems to indicate that it will not expire, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.noslidingexpiration?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> A cache entry that is inserted into the cache with the NoSlidingExpiration field value set as the expiration value should never be evicted because of non-activity in a sliding time window.

So you can do something like the following:

```
memoryCache.Add(new CacheItem("data", data), new CacheItemPolicy
{
    SlidingExpiration = System.Runtime.Caching.NoSlidingExpiration
});
```

Please note the code above might not compile, it's just an example on how to use it.